# Counting the number of times a variable has changed values

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I randomly generate a list.

```
mylist = []
for i in range(0,10):
        s = np.random.choice([-1,0,1])
        mylist.append(s)
```

Now `for x in range(0,100)`. I modify the elements according to some rules, and then count the number of elements of each type, using `counts = Counter(mylist)`

```
for x in range(0,100):
    #some rules
    counts = Counter[mylist]
```

In the beginning the list can be in a state when say the number of -1 is greater than the number of +1's, and then transition from state where the number of +1's is greater than the number of -1's.

Is there way to count the number of times such a transition is made? In addition to this, would it be possible to record the values of x when such a transition is made in a list.

So far, I have tried is to plot this data versus

```
p = counts[1]
m = counts[-1]  
plt.plot(x, p,m)
plt.show()
```

and look for the intersection points. Is there a better way to do this, or is there some built in functionality in python and/or numpy. Also, it would be great if I could score transition to the high- +1 state when when no. of +1 > 1.5 (no. of +1), and to the high -1 state when no. of -1 > 1.5*(no. of +1). (Or some other arbitrary pre-factor, 2, 3 etc. instead of 1 or 1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer supposes that you  try to count a transitions only and don't try to plot values (last paragraph of the question).

If you deal with only a `{-1, 0, 1}` set, perhaps you can sum a values from a list. It's a little faster than add them to counter and gives you a transition info.

And of course it's easier not to sum full list every time, but just increment / decrement a counter inside your logic block when changes occurs.

```
more_ones = True if sum(my_list) > 0 else False
transition_counter = 0
transitions_history = []
for x in range(0, 100): 
    # some rules, which change mylist
    # you can place a transition counter logic right here
    current_sum = sum(my_list)  # one more time, counting inside the logic is faster
    if current_sum < 0 and more_ones:
        transition_counter  += 1
        more_ones = False
        transitions_history.append(x)
    elif current_sum > 0 and not more_ones:  
        transition_counter  += 1
        more_ones = True
        transitions_history.append(x)
```

here I suppose that if sum doesn't intersect zero there's no transition.

Similar approch works in the pre-factor case (if I got the idea right):

```
my_list = [0, 1, -1, -1]  # sample data

factor = 1.5  # some factor
pos_count = my_list.count(1)
neg_count = my_list.count(-1)
more_ones = True if pos_count > factor * neg_count else False  # unclear part - don't know what you plan to do with zeroes
transition_counter = 0
transitions_history = []
for x in range(0, 100):
    # I provide a test logic
    ### CROP HERE ###
    try:
        if x < 3:
            my_list.remove(-1)  # better to decrement/increment pos. and neg. counts here
        elif x >= 3 and x < 5:
            my_list.append(1)
        elif x >= 5 and x < 10:
            my_list.append(-1)
        else:
            my_list.append(1)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    ### CROP HERE ###
    pos_count = my_list.count(1)
    neg_count = my_list.count(-1)
    if neg_count > pos_count * factor and more_ones:
        transition_counter  += 1
        more_ones = False
        # you couldn't store list and need a copy, otherwise it will change values by pointer
        transitions_history.append((x, 'pos_to_neg', [i for i in my_list]))
    elif pos_count > neg_count * factor and not more_ones:
        transition_counter += 1
        more_ones = True
        transitions_history.append((x, 'neg_to_pos', [i for i in my_list]))
```

Sample output:

```
transitions_history
Out:
    [(1, 'neg_to_pos', [0, 1]),
     (9, 'pos_to_neg', [0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]),
     (14, 'neg_to_pos', [0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])]
transition_counter
Out:
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

mylist = []
new_list = list(mylist)
transitions = []

for x in range(0,100): 
    mylist.append(random.choice([1, 0, -1])) # some rules, which change mylist
    is_trans1 = new_list.count(1) > new_list.count(-1) and mylist.count(1) < mylist.count(-1)
    is_trans2 = new_list.count(1) < new_list.count(-1) and mylist.count(1) > mylist.count(-1)
    if is_trans1 or is_trans2:
        transitions.append(x)       
    new_list = list(mylist) # save mylist for the next iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in which element is the most common in your list, then `Counter` has a built-in `most_common()` function you can query:

```
counts = Counter()
for x in range(0, 100):
    # some rules
    s = np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1])
    mylist.append(s)
    if mylist.count(1) > mylist.count(-1) and mylist.count(1) > mylist.count(0):
        counts[1] += 1
    elif mylist.count(-1) > mylist.count(1) and mylist.count(-1) > mylist.count(0):
        counts[-1] += 1
    else:
        counts[0] += 1
    print(counts.most_common())
```

It automatically promotes the most common element (along with its count) to be the first element in the returned list.  Here are some neighbouring returns around a transition point:

```
[(-1, 28), (0, 27), (1, 26)]
[(-1, 28), (0, 27), (1, 27)]
[(1, 28), (-1, 28), (0, 27)]   # Transition here as -1 and +1 both have a count of 28
[(1, 29), (-1, 28), (0, 27)]
```